# Hm... Quick Rebus Time!

Tags: rebus

So I came up with a quick rebus puzzle this morning.
Can you figure out what the answer is?

```
 HM01
 ----
 TM44
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the Pokémon games, [HM01](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/HM01) is Cut, while [TM44](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/TM44) is Rest. So the rebus reads "A cut above the rest".

Comment: easy peasy lemon squeezy :P

Comment: I'm surprised that TM44 hasn't changed from Rest since Red and Blue.